# How to restrict an iOS app to iPad Pro only?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-appstore, development, apple-pencil

As a developer of iOS software, is it possible to restrict an App to only be available on the iPad Pro?

To be more precise, the App we are considering should be restricted to the Apple Pencil, which is currently limited to the iPad Pro.

Is there any way to restrict our App to those devices which support the Apple Pencil?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within Xcode you can specify that an app is iPad only under the "Deployment Info" section of the target's General settings.

Beyond that the way to limit an app to certain devices is by specifying features in the Info.plist under the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key. You can see the options listed on Apple's developer website here: [iOS Device Compatibility Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html)

Unfortunately there does not seem to be an option that limits an app to iPad Pro devices only. You can specify "arm64" which will limit your app to iPad mini second generation and above, iPad Airs and iPad Pro devices. But I can't see an option that says devices that support Apple Pencil only.